# Mongoose not returning full dataset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Model set up like so:

```
var Post = mongoose.Schema({

      "_uid": String,
      "post_title": String,
      "post_content": String,
      "post_date": Date,
      "user": String,
      "slug": String,
      "attached_media": [[
        {
          "format": String,
          "type": String,
          "small": String,
          "medium": String,
          "large": String
        }
      ]],
      "likes_count": Number,
      "likes": [
        {....
```

The key part of this is the attached_media array, as whenever I use the .find({}) command with mongoose none of the array elements return with any data inside them. 
Data is definitely inside them as when I use the mongo command shell I see that the arrays are populated.

My find method:

```
Post.statics.getAll = function getAll(next){
  this.find({})
  .sort({'post_date':'desc'})
  .exec(function(err, doc){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    next(null, doc)
  })
}
```

Mongoose returns:

```
[ { attached_media: [],
    likes: [],
    comments: [],
    __v: 0,
    _uid: '577e67d2a4387d0b1b480e2c',
    user: 'Aaron Griffin',
    post_title: 'This should be a couple of images',
    post_date: Tue Jul 12 2016 13:40:06 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    post_content: '',
    _id: 5784f33681adc21c121a94d1 },
  { attached_media: [],
    likes: [],
    comments: [],
    __v: 0,
    _uid: '577e67d2a4387d0b1b480e2c',
    user: 'Aaron Griffin',
    post_title: 'Hello',
    post_date: Tue Jul 12 2016 13:34:03 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    post_content: '',
    _id: 5784f1cb81adc21c121a94d0 } ]
```

But should return (what the mongo shell returns):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5784f33681adc21c121a94d1"), "post_content" : "", "post_date" : ISODate("2016-07-12T13:40:06.486Z"), "post_title" : "This should be a couple of images", "user" : "Aaron Griffin", "_uid" : "577e67d2a4387d0b1b480e2c", "comments" : [ ], "likes" : [ ], "attached_media" : [ { "large" : "large_f087dd83f697e3742d249e45d47f102b.jpg", "medium" : "medium_f087dd83f697e3742d249e45d47f102b.jpg", "small" : "small_f087dd83f697e3742d249e45d47f102b.jpg", "type" : ".jpg", "format" : "image/jpeg" }, { "large" : "large_fe6dfb7bfcff38883badb800d049dc19.jpg", "medium" : "medium_fe6dfb7bfcff38883badb800d049dc19.jpg", "small" : "small_fe6dfb7bfcff38883badb800d049dc19.jpg", "type" : ".jpg", "format" : "image/jpeg" }, { "large" : "large_527b0b9eb14f4310e535eae2c6e48f4a.jpg", "medium" : "medium_527b0b9eb14f4310e535eae2c6e48f4a.jpg", "small" : "small_527b0b9eb14f4310e535eae2c6e48f4a.jpg", "type" : ".jpg", "format" : "image/jpeg" } ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5784f1cb81adc21c121a94d0"), "post_content" : "", "post_date" : ISODate("2016-07-12T13:34:03.848Z"), "post_title" : "Hello", "user" : "Aaron Griffin", "_uid" : "577e67d2a4387d0b1b480e2c", "comments" : [ ], "likes" : [ ], "attached_media" : [ { "large" : "large_c869348bfc5f12f4099a0f6e2d8941ae.jpg", "medium" : "medium_c869348bfc5f12f4099a0f6e2d8941ae.jpg", "small" : "small_c869348bfc5f12f4099a0f6e2d8941ae.jpg", "type" : ".jpg", "format" : "image/jpeg" } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

The code that runs and logs the query:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    if(req.user.registration_level == 1){
      res.redirect('/signup/complete')
    }
    Post.getAll(function(err, posts){
      // console.log(req.user)
      console.log(posts)
      res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Member feed' , posts: posts, user: req.user });
    })
  } else {
      res.render('index.ejs', { title: 'Express' });
  }
});
```

If anyone knows maybe why this isn't working I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: Can you post your `find()` query?

Comment: ```Post.statics.getAll = function getAll(next){
  this.find({})
  .sort({'post_date':'desc'})
  .exec(function(err, doc){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    next(null, doc)
  })
}```

Comment: where is you console.log ? where you logging what you said mongoose return.s?

Comment: See the above edit :)

Comment: sorry I am clueless. the only thing I can still bate on is, make sure you  re -populate. best of luck

Comment: I appreciate you trying :) anyone else have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I needed to use a Sub-Document that Mongoose provides:

```
var mediaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "format": String,
  "type": String,
  "small": String,
  "medium": String,
  "large": String
})

var Post = mongoose.Schema({
  "_uid": String,
  "post_title": String,
  "post_content": String,
  "post_date": Date,
  "user": String,
  "slug": String,
  "attached_media": [mediaSchema],
  "likes_count": Number,
  "likes": [
...
```

Thanks for everyones help :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you have used array of array there... can you replace it with array of one level like this.

```
var Post = mongoose.Schema({

  "_uid": String,
  "post_title": String,
  "post_content": String,
  "post_date": Date,
  "user": String,
  "slug": String,
  "attached_media": [
    {
      "format": String,
      "type": String,
      "small": String,
      "medium": String,
      "large": String
    }
  ],
  "likes_count": Number,
  "likes": [
    {....
```

Comment: Just changed it and still it doesn't return the full document

Comment: did you tried creating a fresh data. because old data is now wrong. db.posts.remove( { }. don't forget to accept answer if it works. don't down vote if not.

Comment: Just did that, still no luck: 
    ```POST /login 302 152.107 ms - 46
    [ { attached_media: [],
        likes: [],
        comments: [],
        __v: 0,
        _uid: '577e67d2a4387d0b1b480e2c',
        user: 'Aaron Griffin',
        post_title: 'This is new',
        post_date: Tue Jul 12 2016 13:23:37 GMT+0000 (UTC),
        post_content: '',
        _id: 5784ef59193c088c0d0afaf4 },...```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/brya5l 
< shell find,
http://prntscr.com/bryaq9
< Mongoose find

Comment: Do one ting please update your question with all relevant code, and files. including the way you submit and the way you list.